# Stuck at installing laravel/passport programmatically

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-passport

To create a personal access client with passport in laravel, I need to run this command: `php artisan passport:client --personal`

I'm trying to run this command through `Artisan::call('command', ['--flag'=>'value'])`

The issue I'm having here is, passport prompts for an input to name the access token or accept a default one and the command gets stuck there. Is there any way I can give it any input? The `Enter` key press does the work on console.

**Solution**

Default Name: `php artisan passport:client --personal --no-interaction`

Custom Name: `php artisan passport:client --personal --name=AccessTokenName`

Found it in the source: https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/2.0/src/Console/ClientCommand.php

Comment: Why are you trying to go through Artisan instead of the Passport API? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#requesting-tokens

Comment: That command is used to initialize the client, not grant access tokens.

Comment: Yes, to initialize client. My bad. I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're trying to accomplish here. Do you not have access to a console on the machine this is hosted on? Why not just run `php artisan passport:client --personal` from the console and be done?

Comment: I'm trying to make an automatic installer, I need to run this command programmatically where there's no shell access. Not even any function that has access to the cli, like exec().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the command with the `--no-interaction` flag set. See `php artisan passport:client --help` for more options.